# What the gluten look like when kneading for long time on a texture basis

Tags: bread, dough

If developing lots of gluten make the dough harder to be rolled out, why some bread recipes calls for long kneading process, like the brioche dough and pizza dough, and then be rolled out into long size?

And another question, if I did the same dough recipe, the first one is kneaded for 2 minutes, and the other for 10 minutes and then baked, what would be the texture difference between both breads ?

Answer (score 2):

Kneading gives elasticity and strength to your dough. I'm not 100% sure about pizza dough, but a brioche dough requires quite a lot of kneading, to allow for the air created by the yeast during proofing to stretch it. If it's not kneaded, it wont be able to stretch enough, and will be rather flat and dense when baked.

Most doughs are usually rested at cold temperature, and rolled out later. And in the case of brioche, you actually knead it some more while rolling it.